# How to embed youtube livestream chat based on channel id

Tags: html, youtube, embedding

I've been trying to do some basic embedding from Yt on my HTML paged, and I got it to display the livestream itself perfectly. The livestream embed references my channel, so if I decide to livestream whenever, I do not have to change the video id every time to do so.

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UC0F8uoItJ00zVdyJllC-6yA&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&mute=1&origin=http://alecharvey.net"
 title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" autoplay=1 allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Now, the next thing I wanted was to do the same thing but for the livestream's chat. I tried this:

```
<iframe width="350px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?channel=UC0F8uoItJ00zVdyJllC-6yA;embed_domain=alecharvey.net"></iframe>
```

but it didnt work. I figured if i replaced the v=VIDEO_ID with channel=CHANNEL_ID that it would reference the a currently-runnning livestream on my channel and embed the chat from that livestream, but I guess I am wrong. Is there a way of doing this? What is the proper syntax? Do I just have to reference the stream itself to get its chat, like from above?

Thank you for any ***useful/helpful*** advice

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `&` instead of `;`

From this

```
https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?channel=UC0F8uoItJ00zVdyJllC-6yA;embed_domain=alecharvey.net
```

to this

```
https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?channel=UC0F8uoItJ00zVdyJllC-6yA&embed_domain=alecharvey.net
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this thread,
I gave this a try but was unable to get it working based on that edit recommended by Roberts unfortunately.

`<iframe width="350px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?channel=UCeTQOO2-MerayKuv3k12hMg&embed_domain=justdalek.com"></iframe>`

gives me a frame with a monkey "something went wrong"